# select where average with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, average

I have the following query:

```
"SELECT
    bnbs.name,
    bnbs.slug,
    bnbs.city,
    bnbs.website,
    bnbs.description,
    bnbs.profile_picture,
    bnbs.price_low,
    (SELECT AVG(ROUND((ratings.rating_room+ratings.rating_cleanliness+ratings.rating_service+ratings.rating_meals+ratings.rating_general)/5)) FROM ratings) AS average
FROM
    bnbs
        JOIN
            accounts
                ON
                    bnbs.account_id = accounts.account_id
WHERE
    bnbs.average = 3
AND
    bnbs.visible = 1
AND
    accounts.active = 1
AND
    accounts.confirmed = 1";
```

When I **remove** the "bnbs.average = 3" in the where clausule, the query works, but I want to calculate the average rating from **ALL** the ratings for each bnb in the table ratings (each bnb can have more than one rating), and I want to select all the bnbs where the rating = 3, or > 3, or 4, ... I think you get the point.

Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I don't get the point. Any chance of some proper CREATE and INSERT statements AND a desired result?

Comment: the ratings for each bnb are stored in a seperate table (ratings). In want to select all the bnbs where the average rating (eg. a bnb can have multiple rating - each rating in a row) is like 3, or 4.

Answer (score 0):

The `average` field in the select list is a calculated field, not part of the bnbs table, so mysql is probably giving you an unknown field error. Calculated fields can be filtered in the having clause, not in the where clause.

```
SELECT
    bnbs.name,
    bnbs.slug,
    bnbs.city,
    bnbs.website,
    bnbs.description,
    bnbs.profile_picture,
    bnbs.price_low,
    (SELECT AVG(ROUND((ratings.rating_room+ratings.rating_cleanliness+ratings.rating_service+ratings.rating_meals+ratings.rating_general)/5)) FROM ratings) AS average
FROM
    bnbs
        JOIN
            accounts
                ON
                    bnbs.account_id = accounts.account_id
WHERE
    bnbs.visible = 1
AND
    accounts.active = 1
AND
    accounts.confirmed = 1
HAVING average = 3
```

However, the subquery in the select list calculates the same average for all bnbs records, since I do not see any where criteria in it. You can also remove the subquery and add the ratings table in the join list and use group by. In this case you still have to filter in the having clause for the averages you want to see.